# Null pointer exception in onCreateView using FragmentTabHost

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragment-tab-host, webviewclient

I am using a FragmentTabHost which contains three tabs. I am getting a null pointer exception in onCreateView of the 1st tab where i'm trying to add a webViewClient.. I'm new to android and i'm not able to figure out what's wrong with the code...

I used to have a sidebar/hamburger drawer in my main layout file but as soon as i removed that from my activity_lest_see_main xml file.. I started getting a NullPointerException in Tab1Activity.. Please help.. I'm really stuck at this problem.
As soon as i add the sidebar/hamburger drawer back in my lest_see_main.xml file, the code starts running without any error and the app works fine.

I keep getting `NullPointerException` at `mwebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient)` in `Tab1Activity`.

This is what i get in my Logcat along with the NullPointerException at the top -

```
07-28 18:24:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-28 18:24:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6834): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-28 18:24:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6834):     at com.example.itslive.Tab1Activity.onCreateView(Tab1Activity.java:168)
07-28 18:24:52.735: E/AndroidRuntime(6834):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1786)
07-28 14:17:31.274: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:947)
07-28 14:17:31.274: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1126)
07-28 14:17:31.274: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:739)
07-28 14:17:31.274: E/AndroidRuntime(29029):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1489)
```

This is my xml file of the main Activity which extends Fragment Activity

activity_lest_see_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/rev"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height = "match_parent"
 android:layout_gravity="start">

<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/mainContent"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 >
 <android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@android:id/tabhost">

  <LinearLayout 
   android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
   android:orientation="vertical" 
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent">

   <TabWidget 
    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">
    </TabWidget>

    <FrameLayout 
     android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent">
     </FrameLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost> 

    <Button
     android:id="@+id/exit"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:background="@android:color/transparent"
     android:layout_gravity="bottom"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:text = "@string/exit_button"
     android:textColor="@color/blue"
     android:textSize="20sp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

     </RelativeLayout>


     </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my MainActivity java file extending Fragmentactivity

LetsSeeMainActivity.java

```
public class LestSeeMainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
private FragmentTabHost tabHost;
int flag = 0;
int n;
private static final String TAG = "LetsSeeMainActivity";
private AudioManager maudioManager;
Fragment mContent;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lest_see_main);


        maudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);

    final Button exitb = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit);

    exitb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            maudioManager.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FX_KEY_CLICK);
            finish();
        }
    });


    tabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

     tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Tab1", null),
                Tab1Activity.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Tab2", null),
                Tab2Activity.class, null);
        tabHost.addTab(
                tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Tab3", null),
                Tab3Activity.class, null);  
}
```

}

This is my 1st Fragment Activity java file's onCreateView

Tab1Activity.java

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v==null)
    {
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_tab1, container, false);
     mwebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wb1);
     mwebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
     registerForContextMenu(mwebView);

    }
```

this is my activity_tab1.xml file-

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh_layout"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <WebView android:id="@+id/wb1" 
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

 <ProgressBar
 android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:maxHeight="5dp"
 android:minHeight="5dp"
 android:visibility="invisible"
 />

 </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: You can check this [link](http://androhub.com/android-swiperefresh-layout/).

Comment: Thanks but this of no  help.. since my main and only problem is this nullpointerexception.

Comment: Post your complete Logcat

Comment: @AndroidBoy  just edited my question.. I've posted the complete Logcat now..you can check it out..

Comment: @VidurSingh I can't see `activity_tab1` in your xml file. Where is it defined?

Comment: Post more logcat, we can't see the NPE.

Comment: @karthik just edited my question again and re-added it.. let me know if can see it now..

Comment: @hitch.united I've edited my question now.. you'll be able to see the NPE now..

Comment: The nullpointerexception is in line 168 of your TabActivity. If you add the line numbers in your code snippet, we can see which line that is.

Comment: @Christine I have written exactly which line is giving me the nullpointerexception.. 'mwebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient)'...in my Tab1Actvity.java file...

Comment: Still, it's good practice if you post a stacktrace, to include line numbers.

Comment: @Christine Thanks.. will do it from next time..

Answer (score 0):

Try putting

```
mwebView = (WebView) v.findViewById(R.id.wb1);
mwebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
registerForContextMenu(mwebView);
```

in onViewCreated(..).

Comment: Now its giving me nullpointerexception at mwebView.loadUrl("https://www.google.co.in/").. I'm just frustated with with this problem.. my entire project has come to a stop because of this exception